# how to restart list of serves one at a time using powershell?

Tags: powershell

Reboot list of remote serves one by one i.e (1st sever must come online then only script should restart 2nd server or stop the script) using power shell?

```
$Output= @()
$names = Get-content "D:\Dhana\Servers.txt"
foreach ($name in $names){
  if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
  {

   Write-Host "$Name is online and initiating restart"
   Restart-Computer $name -Force
  }
  else{
    $Output+= "$name is offline"
    Write-Host "$Name is offline"
  }
}
$Output | Out-file "D:\Dhana\Offline servers log.csv"
```

Comment: What does "online" entail for you? Is it enough that a server comes up and responds to ICMP (ping) or do you want to make sure, that it is offering it`s service?

Comment: What do you want the script to do, if a server does not come up after reboot?

Comment: **Test-Connection** before continue maybe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection?view=powershell-7

Comment: Use `Test-connection` is not good idea because , your server can responds to ICMP and not working at same time. better way is [enable psremoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting?view=powershell-5.1)
And then check if server starts:
`$testSession = New-PSSession -Computer $Name
if(-not($testSession))
{
    #what do if not loading
}
else
{
   #do something,server accessible.
    Remove-PSSession $testSession
}`
For wait until it become accessible you can use `while(){}` , but if it not starting you receive endless cycle

Comment: If one server must be online first, then it must have a dependency. Why not check for the dependency, e.g. check that the dependent service is running?

Comment: @Manuel Batsching.....server should comes up..pining..should check if some of the mentioned services are running or not once server is online. if it doesn't comes up online script to should stop without touching 2nd server in the list... it would be great if it records of the result... Note : This is for 2k8, 2012 and 2016 Win servers as i am new to power shell please suggest me some code which works. Thank you buddies for response